# Angular 4+ styleguide name od components

Tags: angular

I have some component i angular 4+ that is called

**Money**, that holds several sub components like

**Active, Planned, Finished**

They are inside folder Money. My question is how to name them, like MoneyActiveComponent, MoneyPlannedComponent etc. Or just put them inside folder and name them Active, Planned etc.

I have been looked in some style guide but there is no example like this, any suggestion?

Comment: follow the `File structure conventions` https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: check out this [repo](https://github.com/SiddAjmera/AngularStyleGuide)

Comment: Can somebody make an anaswer please